# What can cause a Lucene Index to be corrupted?

Tags: solr, lucene

I am trying to figure out my strategy for recovering from a corrupted index. To "get a handle" on how often this may happen I'd primarily like to know the things that can cause an index to become corrupted and secondly though not as important if information exists on the probability of these events occurring.

Comment: I don't think index corruption just happens. It's exactly as probable to become corrupt as it is probable that the conditions in your implementation or runtime will make it corrupt. Corruption can be caused by missing or incorrectly formatted index files. A corrupt index exception will provide more debugging information (missing segments file, incorrect version, etc.), which would help, and you should try running [CheckIndex](http://solr.pl/en/2011/01/17/checkindex-for-the-rescue/), to determine what has gone wrong in your index, and check the logs to see if any likely cause comes up there.

Comment: one thing that can cause index corruption (and happened to me once) was killing the hanged solr instance that has ran out of memory while committing. At that point I was able to recover the index from a snapshot. Such a thing isn't very likely especially with the recent versions of Lucene.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. As far as I can tell the only causes are a bug in Lucene/SOLR/some code I write or a hardware failure.

Comment: I've seen a `CorruptIndexException` occur in my Lucene.Net app when attempting to open an index. The app had created the index, which was later edited using Luke. It seems the problem was due to the version of Luke using a newer version of the Lucene engine compared to the engine version used by the app.

Comment: I am using raw lucene API 6.0.0 and faced the issue mentioned by @D_K. My program stopped due to `OutOfMemory` for one run then from next run on wards, index directory never worked.

Comment: @SabirKhan have you tried index checker tool? You can do that from luke: https://github.com/DmitryKey/luke/releases

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time index should be corrupted due to the improper close of writer.

```
IndexWriter writer=new IndexWriter(dir,analyzer,true);
writer.addDocument(doc);
writer.close(false);
```